# Facing Issue In Installation of Superset(2.1.0)) for Creating Visualization Plugins

Tags: docker-compose, installation

I am doing these step to first clone,install and run the superset code repo in my local system -

git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git

cd superset

git checkout 2.1.0

docker-compose up

[Below error for the reference image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPOwP.png)

superset_worker        | Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
superset_worker        | Try 'celery --help' for help.
superset_worker        |
superset_worker        | Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app':
superset_worker        | Unable to load celery application.
superset_worker        | While trying to load the module superset.tasks.celery_app:app the following error occurred:
superset_worker        | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_worker        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 53, in convert
superset_worker        |     return find_app(value)
superset_worker        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 384, in find_app
superset_worker        |     sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
superset_worker        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
superset_worker        |     module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
superset_worker        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 100, in import_from_cwd
superset_worker        |     return imp(module, package=package)
superset_worker        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
superset_worker        |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
superset_worker        |   File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
superset_worker        |   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
superset_worker        |   File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
superset_worker        |   File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
superset_worker        |   File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
superset_worker        |   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
superset_worker        |   File "", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
superset_worker        |   File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
superset_worker        |   File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
superset_worker        |   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
superset_worker        |   File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
superset_worker        |   File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
superset_worker        |   File "", line 850, in exec_module
superset_worker        |   File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
superset_worker        |   File "/app/superset/**init**.py", line 21, in 
superset_worker        |     from superset.app import create_app
superset_worker        |   File "/app/superset/app.py", line 23, in 
superset_worker        |     from superset.initialization import SupersetAppInitializer
superset_worker        |   File "/app/superset/initialization/**init**.py", line 33, in 
superset_worker        |     from superset.extensions import (
superset_worker        |   File "/app/superset/extensions/**init**.py", line 32, in 
superset_worker        |     from superset.utils.async_query_manager import AsyncQueryManager
superset_worker        |   File "/app/superset/utils/async_query_manager.py", line 26, in 
superset_worker        |     from superset.utils.core import get_user_id
superset_worker        |   File "/app/superset/utils/core.py", line 72, in 
superset_worker        |     import bleach
superset_worker        | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bleach'
superset_worker        |
superset_worker        |
superset_worker exited with code 2

I want to do Superset code setup(2.1.0) in my local system  and to develop custom visulization.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me for the latest-dev version too:
[image]

https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/24589#issuecomment-1632389399